# How to get the label/value of a picklist rather than the api name in REST API?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I am new to salesforce.

I am trying to get the chosen value of a `picklist` in an object.

The name of the object is `product__c`. When I pass the `product__c` in the rest api call, it returns me the api names rather than the values. How do I get the actual values?

Basically I trying to mimic the `toLabel(product__c)` of the soql in rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) is probably what you're looking for. Use the [Get Record Data and Object Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_record_ui.htm) resource, and it'll return a bunch of information, including the `value` and `displayValue` (the API name and translated value). You get the data with /services/data/v48.0/ui-api/record-ui/**record-id**. Also, to get all the translations and other metadata, you can use a [describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) call, such as calling /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/**objectName**/describe.

Comment: I'm using the "describe" service but I can't see the translated values. Where can I find them?

Comment: @JorgeValdés see [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#PicklistEntry). You get an entry called picklistValues, that contains the label and value for every picklist entry. The label will be translated to the user's language, while value will be the value stored in the database (the API Name value).